# Django dropdown selection is not working when submit button is pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a dropdown selection and 'submit' button in the page. Some fields disappears upon specific dropdown selection. I can hide/show all other fields but except password field. Whenever I hide the password field with a jquery the submit button doesnot work. 
following are my code files.

1. HTML template django

```js
< script >

  $(document).ready(function() {


    $('#type').change(function(eventObject) {
      if ($(this).val() == 'sercomm') {

        $('.sample').show();
        $('.sample_netip').show();
        $('.sample_password').show();
        $('.sample_username').hide();

      } else {
        $('.sample').show();
        $('.sample_password').show();
        $('.sample_netip').hide();

      }
    }).change();

  });

<
/script>
```

```html
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" role="form">{% csrf_token %} {# dropdown#}
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">{% trans "Mode" %}</label>

    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <select name="type" class="form-control" id="type">
        <option value="ex1" selected>{% trans "ex1" %}</option>
        <option value="ex2">{% trans "ex2" %}</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  {# end of dropdown#}
  <div class="form-group sample">
    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">{% trans "Name" %}</label>

    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="{% trans " Name " %}" maxlength="20" id="name" required pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9\.\-_]+">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group sample">
    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">{% trans "Management Network IP Address" %}</label>

    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="ipaddr" value="192.168.255.129" maxlength="20" required pattern="^(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[0-1]?\d?[1-9]|[0-1]?[1-9][0])(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[0-1]?\d?\d)){3}$">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group sample_netip">
    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">{% trans "Radio Network IP Address" %}</label>

    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="netipaddr" value="192.168.255.129" maxlength="20" required pattern="^(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[0-1]?\d?[1-9]|[0-1]?[1-9][0])(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[0-1]?\d?\d)){3}$">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group sample_username">
    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">{% trans "User Name" %}</label>

    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" value="" maxlength="48" required pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9\.\-_]+">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group sample_password">
    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">{% trans "Password" %}</label>

    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" value="" maxlength="48" required pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9\.\-_]+">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group sample">
    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">{% trans "Description" %}</label>

    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="description" value="" maxlength="48" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9\.\-_ ]+">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">{% trans "Close" %}</button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="create" value="1">{% trans "Create" %}</button>
  </div>


</form>
```

forms.py goes here

```
import re
from django import forms
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

class BaseStationDetailsForm(forms.Form):
 type = forms.ChoiceField(required=True, choices=(('nokia', 'nokia'), ('sercomm', 'sercomm')))
 name = forms.SlugField(error_messages={'required': _('No base station name has been entered')}, max_length=20)
 ipaddr = forms.IPAddressField(error_messages={'required': _('Invalid IP Address')})
 netipaddr = forms.IPAddressField(error_messages={'required': _('Invalid IP Address')}) #test
 username = forms.CharField(error_messages={'required': _('No user name has been entered')}, max_length=48)
 password = forms.CharField(error_messages={'required': _('No password has been entered')}, max_length=48)
 description = forms.CharField(required=False, max_length=48)
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class BaseStation(models.Model):
 name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
 address = models.IPAddressField()
 ipaddress = models.IPAddressField() #tests
 username = models.CharField(max_length=48)
 password = models.CharField(max_length=48)
 description = models.CharField(max_length=48, blank=True, null=True)
 status = models.IntegerField(default=0)

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.name
```

views.py (only the create (post) button is gives :

```
            if 'create' in request.POST:
            form = BaseStationDetailsForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                data = form.cleaned_data
                if basestations and data['name'] in basestation_names:
                    msg = _("Base Station with this name already exists")
                    errors.append(msg)
                elif ip_addresses and data['ipaddr'] in ip_addresses:
                    msg = _("IP address " + data['ipaddr'] + " is already assigned to another Base Station")
                    errors.append(msg)
                else:
                    _type = request.POST.get('type', '')

                    basestation = BaseStation(name=data['name'],
                                              address=data['ipaddr'],
                                              ipaddress=data['netipaddr'],
                                              username=data['username'],
                                              password=data['password'],
                                              description=data['description'],
                                              status='0')
                    # test
                    basestation.save()

                    return HttpResponseRedirect(request.get_full_path())
            else:
                for error_key in form.errors:
                    for error_msg in form.errors[error_key]:
                        errors.append(error_msg)

### other post button functions code deleted

return render_to_response('basestations.html', locals(), context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

---

Example - I can show /hide username/description, the create button works. Only when password field is hidden, the button does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your password field have attribute `required`. Which means that this field is required to submit the form.

To prevent this behavior, during form submission you need to have the following markup.

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
   <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" value="" maxlength="48" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9\.\-_]+">
</div>
```

[Mozilla Reference for HTML validations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Form_validation)

Answer (score 1):

When you are hiding the password field you also have to remove the required attribute with something like this

```
$('#password_field').removeAttr('required');​​​​
```

And then when you show the field add the required again so that the form does not submit without the password.